# C# IFilterSample, can anyone get it to work?

Tags: c#, windows-7, ifilter

I am working on creating a custom IFilter for windows for our application.  I have downloaded the sample code from MS ([Link to MSDN HELP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#running)) and followed the exact steps to test in the readme.txt and on windows 7 it never returns the search terms or ever hits a breakpoint.  BUT I can get filtdump.exe to see the file.  Has anyone got a working version of IFilter??

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windows 7 uses [windows search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which replaces windows desktop search. That example is for windows desktop search. They are not quite the same

Comment: This is not true, I am using the lastest Windows 7.1 SDK example, and it freaking does not work.

Comment: from msdn - _Important  In Windows 7 and later, filters written in managed code are explicitly blocked. Filters MUST be written in native code due to potential CLR versioning issues with the process that multiple add-ins run in._